# How to document only a subset of functions in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Using Sphinx, I need to generate two sets of documentation for my Python app:

1. Contains all my modules/functions
2. Contains only a subset of functions from my modules

I want to use a "tag" in the function docstrings that would indicate whether or not to include the function in the 2nd set of documents.

With `.. only`, I'm able to control which part of the docstring gets included depending on `-t <tagname>` that I provide to sphinx-build. But I'm not able to find any way of filtering out a set of functions to be included in the scope of the documentation based on docstring entries of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

As it usually happens - after posting question you come up with the answer.
Managed to achieve this using https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#skipping-members and putting following code to `conf.py`

```
def include_only_tagged(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    inclusion_tag_format = ".. only:: {}" #can be any pattern here, choose what works for you
    for tag in app.tags.tags:
        if obj.__doc__ is not None and inclusion_tag_format.format(tag) in obj.__doc__:
            return False
    return True
    
def setup(app):
    if(len(app.tags.tags)>0):
        app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', include_only_tagged)
```

So if I use something like `".. only:: subset"` as part of my docstring for any function - that says that whenever I run `sphinx-build -t subset` only this function(s) will be kept in scope of generated documentation.